# Is there any reason why questions asking if a price for an animal is reasonable would be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I had removed it from this question: [What is the procedure for adopting a purebred dog in the United States?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/6798/481), because it was more of a side-comment than a part of the actual question, but it made me think about whether it was something that could be asked separately or not.

It might be something that's included in "shopping questions", but it seems that because prices vary from area to area, and you even have the ability to bargain for a price most of the time, then questions like that would be off-topic for either being too-localised or too broad.

Are there any reasons why those types of questions would be on-topic?

Comment: Not sure I see that as "shopping" to be honest. We do have people that can weigh in on that kind of information, sometimes, with an expert response.

Answer (score 2):

A well written answer to the question "how much should this pet cost?" would include enough data that people should be able to adjust to their local costs.

For example, (since I just took in a stray cat) I can list the amount I paid for his neuter, FIV/FeLV tests, additional vetting that he needed (mostly antibiotics for old injuries), etc. The exact costs of those things will vary (and a rescue will pay less than I did), but it gives someone an idea of what goes into a typical adoption rehoming fee.

Purebreds are more complicated, because you then have to put a value on the breeding. To some extent that's an intrinstic value that folks have to figure out for themselves (it's not worth a premium price to me for a purebred, but other folks have other values).